# Apple Watch error - Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=4 "Not authorized" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Not authorized}

Tags: swift, apple-watch

I am quite stuck with this - I have an app running workout session to collect continuous heart rate. However, when I run it, I keep getting the error below

```
import Foundation
import HealthKit

protocol WorkoutManagerDelegate: AnyObject {
    func didReceiveHealthKitHeartRate(_ heartRate: Double)
    func didReceiveHealthKitStepCounts(_ stepCounts: Double)
}

protocol WorkoutManagerProtocol {
    static func authorizeHealthKit()
    func start()
    func stop()
    func fetchStepCounts()
}

class WorkoutManager: NSObject {
    static let shared = WorkoutManager()
    let healthStore = HKHealthStore()
    let configuration = HKWorkoutConfiguration()
    var workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession!
    var workoutBuilder: HKLiveWorkoutBuilder!
    
    weak var delegate: WorkoutManagerDelegate?
    
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
}

extension WorkoutManager {
    private func handleSendStatisticsData(_ statistics: HKStatistics) {
        switch statistics.quantityType {
        case HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate):
            let heartRateUnit = HKUnit.count().unitDivided(by: HKUnit.minute())
            let value = statistics.mostRecentQuantity()?.doubleValue(for: heartRateUnit)
            let roundedValue = Double( round( 1 * value! ) / 1 )
            delegate?.didReceiveHealthKitHeartRate(roundedValue)
            
        case HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount):
            guard let stepCounts = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount) else {
                return
            }
            let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
            let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
            
            let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepCounts, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { [weak self] (_, result, error) in
                guard let weakSelf = self else {
                    return
                }
                var resultCount = 0.0
                guard let result = result else {
                    print("Failed to fetch steps rate")
                    return
                }
                
                if let sum = result.sumQuantity() {
                    resultCount = sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
                    weakSelf.delegate?.didReceiveHealthKitStepCounts(resultCount)
                } else {
                    print("Failed to fetch steps rate 2")
                }
            }
            healthStore.execute(query)
            return
        default:
            return
        }
    }
    
    private func configWorkout() {
        
        print("inside configworkout")
        configuration.activityType = .walking
        
        do {
            workoutSession = try HKWorkoutSession(healthStore: healthStore, configuration: configuration)
            workoutBuilder = workoutSession?.associatedWorkoutBuilder()
        } catch {
            return
        }
        
        print("inside configworkout -- session")
        workoutSession.delegate = self
        workoutBuilder.delegate = self
        
        workoutBuilder.dataSource = HKLiveWorkoutDataSource(healthStore: healthStore, workoutConfiguration: configuration)
    }
}

extension WorkoutManager: WorkoutManagerProtocol {
    static func authorizeHealthKit() {
        if HKHealthStore.isHealthDataAvailable() {
            let infoToRead = Set([
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .sixMinuteWalkTestDistance)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .restingHeartRate)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .walkingHeartRateAverage)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .oxygenSaturation)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .respiratoryRate)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .walkingStepLength)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .basalEnergyBurned)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .appleExerciseTime)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .appleStandTime)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .vo2Max)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .walkingSpeed)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .walkingAsymmetryPercentage)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .height)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stairAscentSpeed)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRateVariabilitySDNN)!,
                HKSampleType.workoutType()
                ])
            
            
            
            let infoToShare = Set([
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .sixMinuteWalkTestDistance)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .restingHeartRate)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .oxygenSaturation)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .respiratoryRate)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .walkingStepLength)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .basalEnergyBurned)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .vo2Max)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .walkingSpeed)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .height)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .bodyMass)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stairAscentSpeed)!,
                HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRateVariabilitySDNN)!,
                HKSampleType.workoutType()
                ])
            
            HKHealthStore().requestAuthorization(toShare: infoToShare, read: infoToRead) { (success, error) in
                if success {
                    print("Authorization healthkit success")
                } else if let error = error {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("HealthKit not avaiable")
        }
    }
    
    func start() {
        print("Start workout \(Date())")
        print("authoreae")
        WorkoutManager.authorizeHealthKit()
        configWorkout()
        workoutSession.startActivity(with: Date())
        workoutBuilder.beginCollection(withStart: Date()) { (success, error) in
            print(success)
            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func stop() {
        print("Stop workout ")
        
        workoutSession.stopActivity(with: Date())
        workoutSession.end()
        workoutBuilder.endCollection(withEnd: Date()) { (success, error) in
            
        }
    }
    
    func fetchStepCounts() {
        guard let stepCounts = HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .stepCount) else {
            return
        }
        let startOfDay = Calendar.current.startOfDay(for: Date())
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: startOfDay, end: Date(), options: .strictStartDate)
        
        let query = HKStatisticsQuery(quantityType: stepCounts, quantitySamplePredicate: predicate, options: .cumulativeSum) { [weak self] (_, result, error) in
            guard let weakSelf = self else {
                return
            }
            var resultCount = 0.0
            guard let result = result else {
                print("Failed to fetch steps rate")
                return
            }
            
            if let sum = result.sumQuantity() {
                resultCount = sum.doubleValue(for: HKUnit.count())
                weakSelf.delegate?.didReceiveHealthKitStepCounts(resultCount)
            } else {
                print("Failed to fetch steps rate 2")
            }
        }
        healthStore.execute(query)
    }
}

extension WorkoutManager: HKLiveWorkoutBuilderDelegate {
    func workoutBuilder(_ workoutBuilder: HKLiveWorkoutBuilder, didCollectDataOf collectedTypes: Set<HKSampleType>) {
        print("GET DATA: \(Date())")
        for type in collectedTypes {
            guard let quantityType = type as? HKQuantityType else {
                return
            }
            
            if let statistics = workoutBuilder.statistics(for: quantityType) {
                handleSendStatisticsData(statistics)
            }
        }
    }
    
    func workoutBuilderDidCollectEvent(_ workoutBuilder: HKLiveWorkoutBuilder) {
        
    }
}

extension WorkoutManager: HKWorkoutSessionDelegate {
    func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didChangeTo toState: HKWorkoutSessionState, from fromState: HKWorkoutSessionState, date: Date) {
        
    }
    
    func workoutSession(_ workoutSession: HKWorkoutSession, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        
    }
}
```

Here is the error I keep getting - I tried restarting and calling the Workout manager from various locations, but I am stuck as to what these errors mean.

```
Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=4 "Not authorized" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Not authorized}
2023-06-02 00:08:56.685610-0500 ClinicalStudyPal WatchKit Extension[458:46456] [workouts] HKLiveWorkoutBuilder_2A57 [125A]: (#w0) Failed to update target construction state: Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=3 "Unable to transition to the desired state from the Error(6) state (event 1). Allowed transitions from the current state are: {
}" UserInfo={HKErrorParameter=@"", NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to transition to the desired state from the Error(6) state (event 1). Allowed transitions from the current state are: {
}, HKErrorClass=HKStateMachine, HKErrorSelector=_handleEvent:date:error:completion:}
2023-06-02 00:08:56.686088-0500 ClinicalStudyPal WatchKit Extension[458:46507] [workouts] HKLiveWorkoutBuilder_2A57 [125A]: (#w0) Failed to update target construction state: Error Domain=com.apple.healthkit Code=3 "Unable to transition to the desired state from the Error(6) state (event 4). Allowed transitions from the current state are: {
}" UserInfo={HKErrorParameter=@"", NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to transition to the desired state from the Error(6) state (event 4). Allowed transitions from the current state are: {
}, HKErrorClass=HKStateMachine, HKErrorSelector=_handleEvent:date:error:completion:}
```